# How to display Two ActionResults in one view

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have two actionResult in my controller that wroked fine but every ActionResult has a view . My ActionResult return two lists of two different queries . ican't do Union or Join . Actually i'm stuck with this task . i wanna make the two results of the two queries in a same view here my code

First ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult Details(string numQuittance)
    {

        List<QuittTaxe> quittTaxeList = new List<QuittTaxe>();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            var connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connections"].ToString();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString;
            string queryString = "select * from quittance_taxe q inner join taxes t on q.code_taxe = t.code_taxe  where numero_quittance ='" + numQuittance + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConnection);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                QuittTaxe qt = new QuittTaxe();
                qt.code_taxe = row["CODE_TAXE"].ToString();
                qt.Libelle_Taxe = row["LIBELLE_TAXE"].ToString();
                qt.montant_taxe = row["MONTANT_TAXE"].ToString();

                quittTaxeList.Add(qt);
            }

        }

        return View(quittTaxeList);
```

the second one

```
public ActionResult Details_Garantie(string numQuittance)
    {


        List<QuitGarantie> QuitGarantieList = new List<QuitGarantie>();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            var connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connections"].ToString();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString;
            string queryString = "select a.numero_quittance,g.* from MVT_GARANTIE_QUITTANCE a , Garantie g where a.code_garantie = g.code_garantie and numero_quittance ='" + numQuittance + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlConnection);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);



            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                QuitGarantie pt = new QuitGarantie();
                pt.code_branche = row["CODE_BRANCHE"].ToString();
                pt.Libelle_garantie = row["LIBELLE_GARANTIE"].ToString();
                pt.code_garantie = row["CODE_GARANTIE"].ToString();

                QuitGarantieList.Add(pt);
            }

        }

        return View(QuitGarantieList);
    }
```

i want to make those two ActionResults Shown their return values in the same view

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have a single call that makes both queries and returns a viewmodel that contains your two lists:

Viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel{
    public List<QuitGarantie> QuitGarantieList { get; set; }
    public List<QuittTaxe> quittTaxeList { get; set;}
}
```

ActionResult:

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
//your 1º query and code
vm.QuitGarantieList = QuitGarantieList;

//your 2º query and code
vm.quittTaxeList = quittTaxeList;
```

and then:

```
return view(vm);
```

--

edit

I think what i said before should work but without watching what your view code looks like... The only thing that I imagine is to use the @Html.RenderAction() to load the other ActionResult.

In the view that you load first put this code where you want to show the other view:

```
@Html.RenderAction("actionName", "ControllerName", new{ numQuittance = "value" })
```